# Google shows redirected old pages

Tags: seo, google-search

A few months ago, we have redirected some pages with 301 to their new urls. At the moment google shows both old and new urls. It is a simple thing and I cant figure out why old urls not getting deleted. When I visit the old page using google, it redirects with 301. What I am missing here?

[image: 301 network redirection]

Comment: Did you update your sitemap after those redirections and then send it again in Google Search Console? Another direction for investigation would be referral links on other pages or websites which wouldn't have been modifiyed with new urls...

Comment: "google shows both old and new urls." - Where are you seeing this, what type of search are you using?

Comment: Is Google indexing the old URLs even after a few months and showing them in search results, or is Google showing them to you in Google Search Console?

Comment: @gael Yes, sitemap has been updated. And I could not find any referral links.

Comment: @MrWhite I mean two different search results on google.

Comment: Could you have a subdomain with an old version of your website?